# Custom Calendar With Event

Tags: android

I would like to implement a custom calendar like this below image in which when i can press or click on any date. And if click date contains any stored events then the calendar will expand to show the list of events like image, Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: you can use third party library and according to your need you can vary it

Comment: ya i know dear but can you suggest me any link from where i can get hint.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your calendar and it's stored events according to following link :

[AgendaCalendarView](https://github.com/Tibolte/AgendaCalendarView)

Add below lines into your app's build.gradle :

```
compile 'com.github.tibolte:agendacalendarview:1.0.1'
```

Declare this view in your layout like below, providing your own theme and colors if you want :

```
<com.github.tibolte.agendacalendarview.AgendaCalendarView
    android:id="@+id/agenda_calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    agendaCalendar:agendaCurrentDayTextColor="@color/theme_primary"
    agendaCalendar:calendarColor="@color/theme_primary"
    agendaCalendar:calendarCurrentDayTextColor="@color/calendar_text_current_day"
    agendaCalendar:calendarDayTextColor="@color/theme_text_icons"
    agendaCalendar:calendarHeaderColor="@color/theme_primary_dark"
    agendaCalendar:calendarPastDayTextColor="@color/theme_light_primary"
    agendaCalendar:fabColor="@color/theme_accent" />
```

Then configure it in your code with a start and end date associated with a list of events:

```
    // minimum and maximum date of our calendar
    // 2 month behind, one year ahead, example: March 2015 <-> May 2015 <-> May 2016
    Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar maxDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    minDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, -2);
    minDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    maxDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

    List<CalendarEvent> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
    mockList(eventList);

    mAgendaCalendarView.init(eventList, minDate, maxDate, Locale.getDefault(), this);
```

Comment: hi Jon Snow thanks for reply, i try to customize above example according to my requirement but i am fail. can you please help me ?